# Почему не меняется цвет ссылки при наведении

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть блок

```
<li><a href="">Товары</a></li>
```

и его стили

```
.firstlvl li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 146px;
    height: 22px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px 0 0px 8px;
}
.firstlvl li:hover {
    background: #1cb7c9;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

При наведение мышкой весь блок `li` правильно меняет цвет на `#1cb7c9;`  , а вот ссылка внутри не реагирует, как это исправить.
ЗЫ. мне нужно чтобы ссылка меняла цвет именно при наведение на элемент `li`, а не на  `a`. Правило

```
.firstlvl a:hover {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Мне не подходит.

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто:

```css
.firstlvl li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 146px;
    height: 22px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px 0 0px 8px;
}

.firstlvl li:hover a {
    background: #1cb7c9;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="firstlvl">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Товары 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Товары 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Товары 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Товары 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```